Method to Deserialize ROS2 mcap files without ROS environment
I am working with rosbag2 to deserialize ROS 2 logs but am facing an issue where the message definitions have changed over time. Is there a way to deserialize a ROS message without the definitions known at runtime using rosbag2 or a method to overwrite message defintions?
I specifically would like to use rosbag2 rather than mcap_ros2 since I am writing a script in python to decode messages and rosbag2 generally has been faster.
